# Flaxseed oil as insulating oil for wires

Tags: audio, wire, vintage

I've bought clothed wires which look like vintage wires found in old audio equipment. I was expecting they are 'oiled' or waxed but they visually didn't. Now I got flaxseed oil and olive oil available and I prefer to use flaxseed oil for starting. I'm planning to sink those wires in the oil and bake it to let it dry quicker. Is there any suggestion for how long should it be sink and how long, what temperature should it be baked?

Comment: What is the intended effect of oiling the wires?

Comment: Cloth insulated wires were a think 50+ years ago. What are you hoping to achieve by soaking them in oil - they're already insulated?

Comment: why are you asking `how long to sink, and how long to bake?`, when you should be asking `is this a good way to insulate wires?`?

Comment: if the end use is non-electric, then your question is off topic here

Comment: Natural oils have some amount of proteins and will rotten over the time. You may use mineral oil or boiled linseed oil, or tung oil, whatever you try to achieve. Baking not necessary, they are polymerase, except mineral oil.

Comment: @brhans 50 years ago was 1972 8-(   I think cloth-insulated wires would be more like 100 years ago (eg. a house we had was originally fitted with 'knob and tube' wiring which would have had cloth insulation).

Comment: @user263983 mineral oil like silicone oil? I've heard from a person who was working at GE, he said the company uses silicone oil for wire insulation. And another random guy said Jensen's PIO caps use olive oil.

Comment: As a shortcut, consider a traditional linseed oil varnish, thinned 10% or so, which will dry overnight instead of the weeks I find linseed oil needs. The plainer sorts of yacht varnish (NOT polyurethane or 2-pack) should do.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You'd think so, but I have seen German audio equipment from the mid 1960s which, amazingly to me, still used wrapped silk wiring. (Uher Report 4000 tape machine!) I know they didn't have polyurethane in WW2, but apparently Uher stayed with what they knew long after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linseed oil (*derived* from flaxseed oil) is apparently suitable for insulation as it is a "drying oil". Boiled linseed oil is suggested.

Drying agents are sometimes used to speed drying- which are rather undesirable for electrical insulation applications because they involve metallic salts.

Cloth wire insulation itself is (was) typically cotton or sometimes silk on fine wires.

Source: **Standard Handbook for Electrical Engineers** (1949 edition).

No indication of appropriate drying times, however relevant ASTM document D555 indicate that it is highly variable and that the drying process essentially continues indefinitely.

> Since the drying of oils is a continuing process that
> goes on indefinitely, it is difficult to select sharp end points that
> may be measured precisely. The “set-to-touch” point, where the internal cohesion of the film exceeds its adhesion to the
> finger, is probably the sharpest. This point coincides very
> closely with the point where the film changes from a liquid to
> a gel. The “dry time” is more subjective, and it is difficult to get
> close agreement between laboratories, especially for oils with
> relatively long drying times.

Modern cloth covered wire is frequently seen in high-temperature applications, where glass fiber or other refractory fibers are used, generally with binders added to keep the insulation from fraying (at least before exposure to extreme temperatures).

If I was trying this I would start with something like 50 or 60°C (well below 100°C in any case) and dry for at least several times the time to become tacky. If drying is taking too long, increase the temperature  somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a misunderstanding of the use of oil for insulation. As you mentioned in a comment, someone told you that GE used silicone oil for wire insulation. That would be used in something like high power transformers where the silicone provides insulation and also a means of transferring the internal heat to the outside housing. You also mentioned capacitors. Indeed, oil is used in many capacitors as the dielectric material because it can withstand high voltages. However, oil is not used, as far as I know, on regular wires that are not part of transformers or capacitors.